# KendoDropDownList Option Data Items

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'd like to incorporate the KendoDropDownList into my application, however there is a scenario I can't get to work.  The existing application added `data-` attributes to the ListItem class for the drop down (so it rendered as `<option data-xyz="abc" />`).  There is a legitamite reason it's doing that: the information is used to prepopulate the form on the client-side, but the issue I'm having with the kendoDropDownList is that it builds its own list that represents the list items, but it doesn't bring over these data attributes.  Is there a way to link the list item selected to the original item, where I can get the data attributes?  Otherwise, it doesn't look like I'll be able to use the control at all.

EDIT: I was using data attributes to do the initialization, along with `kendo.init`.  Below is the HTML:

```
<select .. data-role="dropdownlist" data-option-label="- Select -">
   <option data-x="y" value="..">..</option>
   <option data-x="y" value="..">..</option>
   .
   .
</select>
```

Javascript to initialize is:

```
kendo.init('body');
```

I wasn't using client-side MVVM binding, FYI.  Kendo, however, builds a UL element with LI elements that represents the dropdown, not using the OPTION elements, and as such when it builds the list, it isn't including all of the attributes.

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you setup the dropdown and when you are trying to get the selected option?

Comment: Updated above, using kendo.init to load the body with the `data-` initializatoin.

Comment: Looks like kendo actually removes the data attributes from the original OPTION element as well as creating new elements. So even referencing the original OPTION does not work.  Can you use a global lookup by value instead of data-attributes?

Comment: @BrianMains any new information about this?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo recreates the element, that is why its attributes are lost. I suggest a wrapper function which copies the `data-` attributes before creating the widget, then after it sets the attributes again:

```
$.fn.myDDL = function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var attrs = [];

  el.find("option").each(function() {
    attrs.push($(this).data());
  });

  el
    .kendoDropDownList()
    .find("option").each(function(i, e) {
      var keys = Object.keys(attrs[i]);

      for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
        $(e).data(keys[k], attrs[i][keys[k]]);
      }
    });

  // Test
  var opt = $("#abc option:eq(0)").data();
  console.log(opt);
};

$(function()
{
    $("#abc").myDDL();
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OcaxU)**</kbd>

This is ugly, I know, but in those cases kendo is limited and doesn't provides resources to deal with its own results. If there is something available I don't know. Templates won't work in your case, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a template?

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-template

Comment: I did but was hoping the data attribute approach would work because we have several pages that rely on using that technique... but if that's what it will take, I will consider.  Thanks.